# Chain rule with partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Please do NOT provide full answers**

> Let $u = x^3f(y/x, z/x)$, show that $x \partial u / \partial x + y \partial u / \partial y + z \partial u / \partial z = 3u$

**Step 1**, we find $\partial u / \partial x$,

but here is my question. How does chain ruling with **partial** derivatives work? I know we consider $y, z$ as constants, basically, my question is

how does something like $\frac{\partial xf(x,x) }{\partial x}$ work?

Comment: We have a function of two variable $f(a,b)$. Lets denote the derivative w.r.t the $a$ vaiable be $f_{(a)}$ and the second $f_{(b)}$. Then $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{-3}{x^4}f+\frac{-y}{x^2}f_{(a)}+\frac{-z}{x^2}f_{(b)}$.

Answer (score 1):

When we have a function like $f(x_{1}(t),x_{2}(t))$, the chain rule becomes
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x_{1}(t),x_{2}(t)) = f_{x_{1}}(x_{1}(t),x_{2}(t))\frac{\partial x_{1}}{\partial t}(t) + f_{x_{2}}(x_{1}(t),x_{2}(t))\frac{\partial x_{2}}{\partial t}(t).$$

Note: I changed variables names a bit from your problem just for ease of notation, but the idea applies to yours just the same.